# Xamarin iOS not finding path for sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin

I am working on an iOS app that needs to have a simple sqlite db. This is in a portable class library using Xamarin. In the code I'm attempting to get the connection to the DB, but I'm not sure where I should be placing the database in my project folder nor if the #if __ IOS__ is even working honestly, but I'm using based on the Xamarin docs here: http://bit.ly/1MxSYey

```
public static SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    #if __IOS__
        var sqliteFilename = "messages.db";
        var docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var db = Path.Combine(docs, "..", "Library", sqliteFilename);
        return new SQLiteConnection(db);
    #endif
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN PCL you should be using interfaces and dependency injection instead using IF directives as in shared solution.

Eg. Xamarin Forms has dependency injection build in (but you can also use another library):

PCL shared library:

```net
public interface ISqlite {
    SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}
```

iOS specific project:

```net
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (SqliteApple))]
public class SqliteApple : ISqlite 
{
    public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection ()
    {
        var sqliteFilename = "messages.db";
        var docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var db = Path.Combine(docs, "..", "Library", sqliteFilename);
        return new SQLiteConnection(db);
    }
}
```

and then use it like that:

```net
var database = DependencyService.Get<ISqlite>().GetConnection();
```

Comment: Every documentation on this uses those path files, and I know that the code to access the file works in another project, what I don't know is where I can place the db to be accessed/if the #if works properly in pcl.

Comment: Actually, you're right. The path is correct (I misunderstood that you want to access native iOS messages database). I'll edit my answer.